# Dotnet yield with IEnumerable<Task<int>> not working

Tags: task-parallel-library, yield-return

Playing around with yield and Task.

The following simple example runs fine.

```cs
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] messages = { "First task", "Second task", "Third task", "Fourth task" };

        var taskList = CreateTaskList(messages).ToList();

        taskList.ForEach(task => task.Start());

        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine("Main method complete. Press enter to finish.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static IEnumerable<Task> CreateTaskList(string[] messages)
    {
        foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            yield return new Task(obj => PrintMessage((string)obj!), message);
        }
    }

    static void PrintMessage(object message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", message);
    }
}
```

But the following does not. Is some deadlock at play? Its stuck at Task.WaitAll. So all that I get from Console is **Before wait all**

```cs
class SimpleClass
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create the simple object
        var simpleObject = new SimpleClass();

        var taskList = CreateTaskEnumerable(simpleObject, 10);

        // Start all of the tasks
        foreach (var task in taskList)
            task.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Before wait all");

        // wait for all of the tasks to complete
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine("After wait all");

        foreach (var task in taskList)
            simpleObject.Counter += task.Result;

        // write out the counter value
        Console.WriteLine("Expected value {0}, Counter value: {1}", 10000, simpleObject.Counter);
        // wait for input before exiting
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to finish");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Task<int>> CreateTaskEnumerable(SimpleClass simpleObject, int numberOfTasks)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)
        {
            yield return new Task<int>((stateObject) =>
            {
                // get the state object
                var localCounter = (int)stateObject!;

                // enter a loop for 1000 increments
                for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)

                    // increment the counters
                    localCounter++;

                return localCounter;
            }, simpleObject.Counter);
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove yield altogether, the above will be as follows, and works. It gives the output as follows. I am expecting the same output from the above as well, but thats stuck. Why?

```
Before wait all
After wait all
Expected value 10000, Counter value: 10000
Press enter to finish
```

The program.

```cs
class SimpleClass
{
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create the bank account instance
        var simpleObject = new SimpleClass();

        // create an list of tasks
        var taskList = new List<Task<int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // create a new task
            var task = new Task<int>((stateObject) =>
            {
                // get the state object
                var localCounter = (int)stateObject!;

                // enter a loop for 1000 increments
                for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)

                    // increment the counters
                    localCounter++;

                return localCounter;
            }, simpleObject.Counter);

            taskList.Add(task);
        }

        // Start all of the tasks
        foreach (var task in taskList)
            task.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Before wait all");

        // wait for all of the tasks to complete
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine("After wait all");

        foreach (var task in taskList)
            simpleObject.Counter += task.Result;
        
        // write out the counter value
        Console.WriteLine("Expected value {0}, Counter value: {1}", 10000, simpleObject.Counter);
        // wait for input before exiting
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to finish");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you are calling `CreateTaskList(messages).ToList()` which forces `CreateTaskList` to yield all tasks before continuing. In the second example you do not call `ToList()`, and the tasks are yielded in the `foreach` and then started. The problem is in line `Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());`. It takes the `IEnumerable` and yields the tasks again, and you are waiting for them to finish, but they are not started. In other words, every time you call `foreach` or `ToList()` on your 'yielded' `IEnumerable`, it will run the method `CreateTaskEnumerable` and create new tasks.

One solution is to call `var taskList = CreateTaskEnumerable(simpleObject, 10).ToList()` or you could just manualy create list in `CreateTaskEnumerable` and return it.

P.S. I would suggest you read how `yield return` works, or test it in https://sharplab.io/. It basically creates `IEnumerable` that gets its data from your method. This means your method will be executed every time your `IEnumerable` is enumerated.